# Regions are Shaded Weirdly

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm following the cup walkthrough on YouTube and for some reason, the inside of my cup has weirdly shaded regions.  Is there any way to fix this easily?  Or did I have an incorrect setting and I'll have to redo it?  I'm entirely new to this software, so any explicit details would be welcome.  Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: check doubles, recalculate normals, add a loop near the bottom edge to avoid subsuf modifier artifacts

Comment: recalculate normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, in a comment, you should at least 
- in edit mode
- check doubles <kbd>W</kbd> and choose "remove doubles"
- recalculate normals <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

and in general check that you don't have duplicated geometry.

about the weird shading in the bottom faces, this is what happens, and how to solve (using a simple cylinder):

[image]

what happens is the effect of the bottom face being distorted by the subdivision surface modifier, without having some more supporting geometry to calculate a better shape for that 90° angle between the bottom and the sides.

here is this problem shown as flat shading

[image]

and here with smooth shading: less ugly but still visible.

[image]

To fix this weird bottom shades, we need to add some supporting geometry. 
In edit mode, add a loop <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

and slide it down almost to the bottom, confirm.

[image]

Now we need to do something similar for the bottom (n-gon) face.

[image]

Select it and delete (only faces)

[image]

now select this edge circle and extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, then press <kbd>esc</kbd> to stop the extrusion,

[image]

and instead scale it towards the center, using <kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

now extrude the inner circle (selected) again towards the center

[image]

and lastly close the inner small circle left open with <kbd>F</kbd>: it will create a small n-gon, but it won't create issues here. It could be converted to triangles or just quads, if needed.

[image]

Now, back into object mode, the subsurf is no more creating those artifact, since ther is now enough geometry on that corner to allow for a nice, uifomr smoothing.

[image]

Comment: It seems that removing doubles did nothing, but I selected everything with `A` and recalculated normals with `control + n` and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Also, I’m a complete beginner with Blender, so it might be worth mentioning in your solution to use A to select everything before trying the recalculate normals or removing doubles.